# WARNING: You don't have <a directory> in your PATH, gem executables will not run

Tags: ruby

I installed a tools package my friend recommended and this is what I keep getting when I try to upgrade. My system has also started freezing after I installed the tools.

```
ryan1@ryan1:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
\Setting up wpscan (1.1-bt3) ...
WARNING:  You don't have /home/ryan1/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed mime-types-2.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mime-types-2.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for mime-types-2.0...
WARNING:  You don't have /home/ryan1/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing typhoeus:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/ryan1/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ryan1/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
WARNING:  You don't have /home/ryan1/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed xml-simple-1.1.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for xml-simple-1.1.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for xml-simple-1.1.3...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/wpscan.postinst: line 7: svn: command not found
dpkg: error processing wpscan (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wpscan
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 25):

Add to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$(ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir')/bin
```

source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ruby#Setup

Comment: didn't solved the problem in my case, I am still asked to add a different directory from  the one found by `ruby -e 'puts Gem.user_dir'` (I am under Cygwin). Gem.user_dir is */home/$myUserName/.gem/ruby/2.6.0* but `gem install $anyGem` returns: `WARNING:  You don't have /home/$myUserName/bin in your PATH, gem executables will not run.`  Do not know where this custom path is found by ruby.

Comment: ... worked adding the requested path to the PATH ...

Answer (score 11):

First message:

```
WARNING:  You don't have /home/ryan1/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin in your PATH,
    gem executables will not run.
```

You need to add the directory to your PATH environment variable:

```
export PATH="/home/ryan1/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin:$PATH"
```

The second error may or not be related to this.